# How to recover a value from SQL queries in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a `function javascript`, that compare two values of 2 turnover of 2 results `SQL queries`. The problem is this function return just one line knowing that I have more than 300 lines.
Tihs following my code:

```
var query1 = {{repair_semestre1}};
var query2 = {{repair_semestre2}};

var data = {};
[query1, query2].forEach(function (query, semester) {
    query.Client.forEach(function(clientId, index) {
        var client = data[clientId] = data[clientId] || {};
        var clientArt = client[query.LRU[index]] = client[query.LRU[index]] || [0, 0];
        clientArt[semester] = query.round[index];
    });
});

// Now report on that data
for (client in data) {
    for (article in data[client]) {
        var turnovers = data[client][article];
        return("Client: " + client + ", art.: " + article 
                  + ", semester t/o: " + turnovers
                  + " " + (turnovers[0] === turnovers[1] ? "equal" : 
                          turnovers[0] < turnovers[1] ? "increase" : 
                                                        "decrease"));
    }
}
```

The values of the 2 `SQL queries` change dynamically according the choice of the user in the interface, also the values of line returned by this function above change.
Can you please tell me why this function return just one line ?
Thank you.

it worked well now, I changed it like this:

```
var query1 = {{repair_semestre1}};
var query2 = {{repair_semestre2}};
var data = {};
[query1, query2].forEach(function (query, semester) {
    query.Client.forEach(function(clientId, index) {
        var client = data[clientId] = data[clientId] || {};
        var clientArt = client[query.LRU[index]] = client[query.LRU[index]] || [0, 0];
        clientArt[semester] = query.round[index];
    });
});

// Now report on that data
var output = [];
for (client in data) {
    for (article in data[client]) {
        var turnovers = data[client][article];
              output.push(formatName(client,article,turnovers));
        }
}

            return {
             output: output 
            };
function formatName(client,article,turnover) {

    return("Client: " + client + ", art.: " + article 
                  + ", semester t/o: " + turnovers
                  + " " + (turnovers[0] === turnovers[1] ? "equal" : 
                          turnovers[0] < turnovers[1] ? "increase" : 
                                                        "decrease"));

}
```

Maybe because, on Palantir we have a special syntax.
Thank you @trincot.

Comment: Please provide the exact values for `query1` and `query2` for which you have the problem. Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Well then there is no question.

Comment: I'm sorry but it does not working in my example, really I can't understand why.

Comment: We cannot do anything (we have no crystal ball), unless you provide the code with which the problem can be *reproduced*.

Comment: @trincot thank you, it worked. I changed it like above , I edited my question.

Comment: NB: You cannot have a `return` statement when not in a function.